# Saving Google API response in php variable

Tags: php

I would like to call a php function which will process a google API call and save particular variable so I can work with it.
I know below code won´t work but I hope it will give you an idea what I want to do.
Thank you in advance for your advise.

```
function callGoogleAPI () {
// calling the fGoggle spi somehow
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=45.908133,-77.047119&timestamp=1472106746 
$dstOffset = dstOffset;

}
```

When the function is executed I should have value "3600" saved in my dstOffset variable.

Thank you

Vinny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very basic question. You can call api via [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/file_get_contents) or via [curl](http://php.net/curl_exec) then decode json with [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode) function.

```
function callGoogleAPI () {
   // calling the fGoggle spi somehow
    $content = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=45.908133,-77.047119&timestamp=1472106746');
    $content = json_decode($content, true); 
    $dstOffset = $content['dstOffset'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using REST APIs in PHP is a three step process.

1) You cal the API and store the returned data in a variable

```
$maps_content = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=45.908133,-77.047119&timestamp=1472106746');
```

2) You convert the JSON object in an associative array

```
$maps_array = json_decode($content, true);
```

3) You start working with the data in your array

```
 $dstOffset = $content['dstOffset'];
```

To see what your variable looks like, don't forget to var_dump

```
var_dump($maps_array);
```